# Spring data - MongoDB - textScore

Tags: mongodb, search, spring-data

I use this methode to search Projects in my application

```
 @Query("{$text : { $search : ?0 } }")
List<Project> findProjectBySearchString(final String searchString);
```

Now I have read that I can add scores to the search result like this:

```
{ score : { $meta : "textScore" } }
```

My question now would be if i can add **{ score : { $meta : "textScore" } }** to my query.
I tried it with

```
@Query("{$text : { $search : ?0 }, { score : { $meta : textScore } } }")
List<Project> findProjectBySearchString(final String searchString);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You can use mongoTemplate.

Comment: Is there also a possibility with @Query?

Comment: Not sure. But you can use mongoTemplate along with MongoRepository.

Comment: Try annotating the meta score field in the project pojo with @TextScore annotation and see it helps.